# python: minimum value within specified bounds for an array

Tags: python, arrays, max, min

Say I have an array  a = [-1.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 5, 3]

Is there a way to find a min element which is within a=0.2 to b=2

In this particular example the answer will be 0.5.

I want to perform this computation in python. .

Comment: Do you know how to get the elements within that range? Do you know how to get the minimum of some elements?

Comment: no i do not know how to do  the first question that you asked. can you please tell me that. i know how to handle the 2nd part then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`filter(predicate, list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to eliminate the out-of-bounds values, then use [`min(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) on the remaining elements:

```
a = [-1.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 5, 3]
assert 0.5 == min(filter(lambda x: 0.2 <= x <= 2, a))
# or
assert 0.5 == min(x for x in a if 0.2 <= x <= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [-1.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 5, 3]
r1=0.2 
r2=2
l=[]
for i in a:
    if i>r1 and i<r2:
        l.append(i)
print(min(l))
```

I have considered strictly inside two given value,  use **>=** and **<=** if both are to be included .Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the list with your bounds (`Min=0.2` and `Max=2`), you can get the elements between by indexing after sorting the extended list:

```py
a =  [-1.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 5, 3]
# Define bounds
Min = 0.2
Max = 2
# Extend and sort list with integrated bounds
a = sorted(a + [Min, Max])
# Slicing and get all the elements between bounds
print(min(a[a.index(Min)+1:a.index(Max)]))
# 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy:

```
a = np.array([-1.2, 1, 0.5, 4, 5, 3])
min(a[(a<2) & (a > 0.2)])
```